# Leaflet: Map tile request, hidden key/secret via proxy

Tags: leaflet, tiles, php, proxy, request

I would like to request a Leaflet tilelayer without exposing my API key and secret. For example, using the [UrtheCast API](https://www.urthecast.com) (but would apply to other similar APIs that embed api_key and api_secret in the URL), I am provided a map tiles URL like the following:

https://tile-{s}.urthecast.com/v1/rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}?api_key=MY_API_KEY&api_secret=MY_API_SECRET&cloud_coverage_lte=20&acquired_gte=2016-02-26T08:00:00.000Z&acquired_lte=2016-04-27T06:59:59.999Z

I can then load the tiles in Leaflet like:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer('https://tile-{s}.urthecast.com/v1/rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}?api_key=MY_API_KEY&api_secret=MY_API_SECRET&cloud_coverage_lte=20&acquired_gte=2016-02-26T08:00:00.000Z&acquired_lte=2016-04-27T06:59:59.999Z').addTo(map);
```

But, anyone looking at my JavaScript code would know my api key and secret.

[The docs](https://developers.urthecast.com/docs/map-tiles) give the following warning: All apps developed are encouraged to be used internally or via a proxy. Otherwise there is a risk of exposing your API key and secret.

How can I make a proxy (preferably using PHP) to make a hidden call for Leaflet map tiles?

Comment: But now I can read your api keys from the php script?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84089)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you just need a PHP script that acts as a middle man and does the fetching for you, then returns what it gets directly to the client. I converted your JS snippet above into the relevant parts below.

Notice that the url in your Leaflet `tileLayer` example has been changed to a PHP endpoint with URL parameters: `?s={s}&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}`

Next, the PHP script receives the URL parameters and concatenates them into a URL formatted for your `urthecast.com` assets.

Note that if your tiles are JPEGs, you'll need to change the `Content-Type` header in the PHP file.

Here's the relevant JS part:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer('http://yourdomain.com/get-tiles-proxy.php?s={s}&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}').addTo(map);
```

And here's the relevant PHP part:

```
<?php
    // get-tiles-proxy.php

    // Ingest the URL parameters
    $s = $_GET["s"];
    $z = $_GET["z"];
    $x = $_GET["x"];
    $y = $_GET["y"];


    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Concatenate the URL parameters into a properly-formatted url for your tile provider
    $path = 'https://tile-'.$s.'.urthecast.com/v1/rgb/'.$z.'/'.$x.'/'.$y.'?api_key=MY_API_KEY&api_secret=MY_API_SECRET&cloud_coverage_lte=20&acquired_gte=2016-02-26T08:00:00.000Z&acquired_lte=2016-04-27T06:59:59.999Z';

    // Then just return it..
    echo file_get_contents($path);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Makes total sense now that I see it, although as someone with only the faintest grasp on PHP, I never would have got it on my own. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. It was a fun question to answer. :)

Comment: sorry if I jump in after an year... I have a similar problem with tileLayer.wms, but this solution didn't work for me... See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258261/need-to-proxy-a-tilelayer-wms-request